# jQuery Ajax fails only in Safari but other browsers are working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a javascript function to call ajax to write some stuff to database. So far it has worked on chrome and firefox without any problem. However, Safari randomly fails without much clue. (This is tested within localhost)

This is the error :

```
write failed : {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

This is my ajax function :

```
function writeToDB() {
      var data = {
        setting: 'some data'
      } ; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Admin/write_to_db',                    
        data: {
            data: 
       btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))))
        },                    
        success: function(response) {
            consoe.log('success');    
            console.log('response : ' + JSON.stringify(response));                              
        },
        error: function(response) {

            console.log('write failed : ' + 
        JSON.stringify(response));

        },
        complete: function(response) {
            console.log('completed');
        },        
    });

   }
```

I simplified the actual function for ease of reading. I have tried many similar responses given for a similar problem but nothing worked. Pls help me with this. Thank You.

Comment: Why are you encoding and then unescaping? They just undo each other.

Comment: Check the Network tab of the web console to see what the server response is.

Comment: Sorry about the settings assignment, it's a typo.

Comment: Hi Barmar, got to thank you for two things. #1 pointing out the unescaping thingy which i totally overlooked. #2 i have seen the networks tab at least a hunderd times, but now i was observing it just as i was triggering some event and i saw in a flash one of the functions was in red font which i believe is the offending script. Will check on it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix the problem.
The above function writeToDB is triggered by a button click. So all that i had to do is add 
      `event.preventDefault()`
to the function. That worked!